# Nginx not serving my test Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, nginx, passenger

I have issue with nginx server on my Ubuntu 14.04 VPS. I successfully installed Passenger (latest) and Nginx. Now I created test Rails app (rails 4.2.3). Path of my app is /home/testapp/public;

In /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf I have this settup:

```
user  root;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    passenger_root /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/passenger-5.0.15;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/wrappers/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;


    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

 #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        root /home/testapp/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env production;
        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }

    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    server {
        listen       8001;

        server_name  testapp.com;
        passenger_enabled on;
        root /home/testapp/public;


        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    }



    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

As you can see there are two server configuration on port 80 and 8001. Going to  both port I have result default nginx page.

I don't getting any errors neither from Passenger,Nginx,Rails  everything is okay.

NOTE: At installation of Passenger and nginx module I didn't get sites-available and sites-enabled folders, so I created both at /opt/nginx/ path.

What I need to do to show my rails testapp instead nginx default page ?

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04 Nginx sites-enabled folders are installed here: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled, and config file is /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all  I needed in server tag:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    passenger_enabled on;
    root /home/testapp/public;
    rails_env production;
}
```

And also removed:

```
location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your port 80, 8001 configurations remove the

```
location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

part as this is overriding the `root /home/testapp/public;` directive